# Web-socket connection getting disconnected after one handshake in node.js and react

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, server

I am trying to build a simple Chatroom where multiple users can post the messages.I have setup the node web socket and it's broadcasting for a single message, but it closes the connection immediately after that.

This includes react on the front-end and node.js on the backend.
For simplicity i am storing and retrieving all the messages in a json file.
I am using ws: a node.js websocket library to setup the socket connection.
In client side i am using browsers WebSocket instance and listening on the same port.

```
    // In server.js (Backend)
    const server = http.createServer(doOnRequest)
    const WebSocket = require('ws')
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 1994 })

    wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN){
    client.send(data);
    }
    });
    });
    ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('server conn closed');
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('closed by server console. log');
    }, 2000);
    })
    });

    function doOnRequest(request, response) {
    // This functions handles all the get and post calls and stores 
    it in a file
    }
    const server = http.createServer(doOnRequest)
    server.listen(3001);

    // IN Chatroom.js ( UI )

    const URL = 'ws://localhost:1994'
    class Chatroom extends React.Component {
    ws = new WebSocket(URL)
    constructor(props) {
    ////// binding classes declaring state //// 
    }
    componentDidMount() {
    this.ws.onopen = () => {
    console.log('connected')
    }

    this.ws.onmessage = evt => {
    // on receiving a message, add it to the list of messages
    let x = this.state.messageList;
    x ? x.push(JSON.parse(evt.data)) : [JSON.parse(evt.data)];
    this.setState({
    messageList: x,
    value: ''
    });
    }

    this.ws.onclose = () => {
    console.log('disconnected')
    }

    this.renderOlderMessages();
    }
    renderOlderMessages() {
    // render older messages using GET request
    }

    addNewMessage(chatObj) {

    // let res = a Post request (with Request body as chatObj).
    res.then(() => {
    this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(chatObj))
    let x = this.state.messageList;
    x ? x.push(chatObj) : [chatObj];
    this.setState({
    messageList: x,
    value: ''
    });
    });

    }

    render() {
    return (
    <div> 
    /// render old messages ///
    </div>

    <div>
    <form> 
    Input ---> New message ---> Submit
    </form>
    </div>
    )
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi mate, can you provide the response/error where you detect the closed connection ?

Comment: It immediately goes into the 'onclose' event and then console's 'disconnected'. After that if trying to send another message it throws this error ---->                                WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1994/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ,  or the other error which pops up sometimes is ---->  Failed to execute `send` on `Websocket`: Still in CONNECTING state